# php modifying textarea input with trim

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, trim

I'm trying to format the users input so that it can meet the conditions in my string comparison function, as you know with string comparison extra spaces, tabs, and "enter(newline)" are considered. So the idea is format the users input before running string comparison function. Currently extra spaces, tabs and the "enter(newline)" problem has been partially solved.

Here's my code and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eSE9Y/2/

html

```
<textarea id="address"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="Validate" value="Validate" onClick="valbtn()">
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Validate").click(function () {
    $('#address').val($('#address').val().replace(/\s+/g,' '));
    });
});
```

But the problem is if a users first and ending input is enter or a space, it will still mess up the string comparison function, until I find the PHP trim, how can i utilize this php function to fit/solve the problem. Any suggestion/opinion is appreciated.

Comment: You should replace your JS validation implementation by an AJAX request to a (simple) php trim functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know about the JavaScript [`trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) function, right? Or the jQuery [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) function?

#### `trim()`:

> The `trim()` method removes whitespace from both ends of the string.

**Usage:**

```
$("#Validate").click(function () {
    $('#address').val(function() { return this.value.trim(); });
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/48QMN/3/)

---

#### `$.trim()`:

> **Description:** Remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a
>   string.

**Usage:**

```
$("#Validate").click(function () {
    $('#address').val(function() { return $.trim($(this).val()); });
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/48QMN/)

Comment: thank you sir, honestly I'm not familiar to this functions I was used to php functions because of its documentation.

Comment: No problem. Useful documentation for JS can be found on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) and jQuery also provides great docs (http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use `trim()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Validate").click(function () {
    $('#address').val($('#address').val().replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim())
    });
});
```

[**FFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/eSE9Y/10/)

or you can use `replace()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Validate").click(function () {
    $('#address').val($('#address').val().replace(/\s+/g,' ').replace(/\s+$/g,'').replace(/^\s+/g,''));
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/eSE9Y/8/)